# Session windows flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Can someone please help me understand when and how is the window (session) in flink happens? Or how the samples are processed?

For instance, if I have a continuous stream of events flowing in, events being request coming in an application and response provided by the application.
As part of the flink processing we need to understand how much time is taken for serving a request.

I understand that there are time tumbling windows which gets triggered every n seconds which is configured and as soon as the time lapses then all the events in that time window will be aggregated.

So for example:
Let's assume that the time window defined is 30 seconds and if an event arrives at t time and another arrives at t+30 then both will be processed, but an event arrivng at t+31 will be ignored.

Please correct if I am not right in saying the above statement.

Question on the above is: if say an event arrives at t time and another event arrives at t+3 time, will it still wait for entire 30 seconds to aggregate and finalize the results?

Now in case of session window, how does this work? If the event are being processed individually and the broker time stamp is used as session_id for the individual event at the time of deserialization, then the session window will that be created for each event? If yes then do we need to treat request and response events differently because if we don't then doesn't the response event will get its own session window?

I will try posting my example (in java) that I am playing with in short time but any inputs on the above points will be helpful!

## process function

DTO's:

```
public class IncomingEvent{
    private String id;
    private String eventId;
    private Date timestamp;
    private String component;
    //getters and setters
}
public class FinalOutPutEvent{
    private String id;
    private long timeTaken;
    //getters and setters
}
```

===============================================
Deserialization of incoming events:

public class IncomingEventDeserializationScheme implements KafkaDeserializationSchema {

```
private ObjectMapper mapper;

public IncomingEventDeserializationScheme(ObjectMapper mapper) {
    this.mapper = mapper;
}

@Override
public TypeInformation<IncomingEvent> getProducedType() {
    return TypeInformation.of(IncomingEvent.class);
}

@Override
public boolean isEndOfStream(IncomingEvent nextElement) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public IncomingEvent deserialize(ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record) throws Exception {
    if (record.value() == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        IncomingEvent event = mapper.readValue(record.value(), IncomingEvent.class);
        if(event != null) {
            new SessionWindow(record.timestamp());
            event.setOffset(record.offset());
            event.setTopic(record.topic());
            event.setPartition(record.partition());
            event.setBrokerTimestamp(record.timestamp());
        }
        return event;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

===============================================

## main logic

```
     public class MyEventJob {

private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    MyEventJob eventJob = new MyEventJob();

    InputStream inStream = eventJob.getFileFromResources("myConfig.properties");
    ParameterTool parameter = ParameterTool.fromPropertiesFile(inStream);
    Properties properties = parameter.getProperties();
    Integer timePeriodBetweenEvents = 120;
    String outWardTopicHostedOnServer = localhost:9092";
    DataStreamSource<IncomingEvent> stream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>("my-input-topic", new IncomingEventDeserializationScheme(mapper), properties));
    SingleOutputStreamOperator<IncomingEvent> filteredStream = stream
        .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<IncomingEvent>() {
            long eventTime;
            @Override
            public long extractTimestamp(IncomingEvent element, long previousElementTimestamp) {
                return element.getTimestamp();
            }
            @Override
            public Watermark getCurrentWatermark() {
                return new Watermark(eventTime); 
            }
        })
        .map(e -> { e.setId(e.getEventId()); return e; });
    SingleOutputStreamOperator<FinalOutPutEvent> correlatedStream = filteredStream
        .keyBy(new KeySelector<IncomingEvent, String> (){
            @Override
            public String getKey(@Nonnull IncomingEvent input) throws Exception {
                return input.getId();
            }
        })
        .window(GlobalWindows.create()).allowedLateness(Time.seconds(defaultSliceTimePeriod))
        .trigger( new Trigger<IncomingEvent, Window> (){
            private final long sessionTimeOut;
            public SessionTrigger(long sessionTimeOut) {
                this.sessionTimeOut = sessionTimeOut;
            }
            @Override
            public TriggerResult onElement(IncomingEvent element, long timestamp, Window window, TriggerContext ctx)
                    throws Exception {
                ctx.registerProcessingTimeTimer(timestamp + sessionTimeOut); 
                return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
            }
            @Override
            public TriggerResult onProcessingTime(long time, Window window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
                return TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE;
            }
            @Override
            public TriggerResult onEventTime(long time, Window window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
                    return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
            }
            @Override
            public void clear(Window window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
                //check the clear method implementation
            }
        })
        .process(new ProcessWindowFunction<IncomingEvent, FinalOutPutEvent, String, SessionWindow>() {
        @Override
        public void process(String arg0,
                ProcessWindowFunction<IncomingEvent, FinalOutPutEvent, String, SessionWindow>.Context arg1,
                Iterable<IncomingEvent> input, Collector<FinalOutPutEvent> out) throws Exception {
            List<IncomingEvent> eventsIn = new ArrayList<>();
            input.forEach(eventsIn::add);
            if(eventsIn.size() == 1) {
                //Logic to handle incomplete request/response events
            } else if (eventsIn.size() == 2) {
                //Logic to handle the complete request/response and how much time it took
            }
        }
    } );
        FlinkKafkaProducer<FinalOutPutEvent> kafkaProducer = new FlinkKafkaProducer<>(
                outWardTopicHostedOnServer,            // broker list
                "target-topic",            // target topic
                new EventSerializationScheme(mapper));
    correlatedStream.addSink(kafkaProducer);
    env.execute("Streaming");
}
```

}

Thanks
Vicky

Comment: I have answered the theoretical questions although I don't quite understand Your issues with request-response windowing, so I will edit my anwer if You post some example.

Comment: Some of what you've said about Flink's windows isn't correct. But it's also not clear why you would use windowing at all. Can you explain why you are looking at session windows as a solution for your use case? How do you intend to match up the request and response events?

Comment: @david: thanks for investing your time at my query. The reason I am think I need to use session windows is that I am not certain if the request and response event will fall in the same window. For instance my request and response can differ from each other by say 3 seconds. But my request arrives at t+29 seconds while my response arrives at t+32 seconds. Now potentially what I need to be able to do is calculate the delta between the 2 events but as you see they fall in 2 different windows which essentially means I won't be able to process them.  Please suggest if that makes sense now!

Comment: @dominik: Thanks for your reply! I will paste an example soon enough and may be that can help me clarify the doubts a bit more!

Comment: What's not clear is why you are thinking to use windows at all. This seems like a situation where either a RichFlatMap or a ProcessFunction will probably be much easier. But the real mystery is how do you recognize the response event that goes with a specific request event? If you'll explain that we can show you how to measure the delay between them. Do they share a sessionId?

Comment: @DavidAnderson; @Dominik: I have added a sample using the process function.The request and response will be identified using the id of the event, which ideally shall be same for the 2 events.

Comment: @DominikWosiński , DavidAnderson In the attached example I  appreciate if you can provide any inputs/improvements/insights if any!

Answer (score 2):

From your description, I think you want to write a custom [ProcessFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/ProcessFunction.html), which is keyed by the `session_id`. You'll have a `ValueState`, where you store the timestamp for the request event. When you get the corresponding response event, you calculate the delta and emit that (with the `session_id`) and clear out state.

It's likely you'd also want to set a timer when you get the request event, so that if you don't get a response event in safe/long amount of time, you can emit a side output of failed requests.

Comment: I have added a sample code with Process Window. The aim is to be able to aggregate the request and response events.

Answer (score 0):

So, with the default trigger, each window is finalized after it's time fully passes. Depending on whether You are using `EventTime` or `ProcessingTime` this may mean different things, but in general, Flink will always wait for the Window to be closed before it is fully processed. The event at t+31 in Your case would simply go to the other window.

As for the session windows, they are windows too, meaning that in the end they simply aggregate samples that have a difference between timestamps lower than the defined gap. Internally, this is more complicated than the normal windows, since they don't have defined starts and ends. The Session Window operator gets sample and creates a new Window for each individual sample. Then, the operator verifies, if the newly created window can be merged with already existing ones (i.e. if their timestamps are closer than the gap) and merges them. This finally results with window that has all elements with timestamps closer to each other than the defined gap.

Answer (score 0):

You are making this more complicated than it needs to be. The example below will need some adjustment, but will hopefully convey the idea of how to use a `KeyedProcessFunction` rather than session windows.

Also, the constructor for `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor` expects to be passed a `Time maxOutOfOrderness`. Not sure why you are overriding its `getCurrentWatermark` method with an implementation that ignores the `maxOutOfOrderness`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    DataStream<Event> events = ...

    events
        .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new TimestampsAndWatermarks(OUT_OF_ORDERNESS))
        .keyBy(e -> e.sessionId)
        .process(new RequestReponse())
        ...
}

public static class RequestReponse extends KeyedProcessFunction<KEY, Event, Long> {
    private ValueState<Long> requestTimeState;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration config) {
        ValueStateDescriptor<Event> descriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<>(
                "request time", Long.class);
        requestState = getRuntimeContext().getState(descriptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(Event event, Context context, Collector<Long> out) throws Exception {
        TimerService timerService = context.timerService();

        Long requestedAt = requestTimeState.value();
        if (requestedAt == null) {
            // haven't seen the request before; save its timestamp
            requestTimeState.update(event.timestamp);
            timerService.registerEventTimeTimer(event.timestamp + TIMEOUT);
        } else {
            // this event is the response
            // emit the time elapsed between request and response
            out.collect(event.timestamp - requestedAt);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext context, Collector<Long> out) throws Exception {
         //handle incomplete request/response events
    }
}

public static class TimestampsAndWatermarks extends BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<Event> {
    public TimestampsAndWatermarks(Time t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public long extractTimestamp(Event event) {
        return event.eventTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @david.. apologies for a very late reply. I was pulled into different things.. I appreciate your response and the example. Will definitely try once and get back with my findings..